# Visual Studio 2019 "cannot open include file" for every project

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-studio-2019

After formatting an HDD (projects are placed there, while VS2019 installation is on SSD), VS2019 stopped building projects with the errors list kind of "cannot open source file "something.h"", and the output window prints:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory
```

Tried to repair the program in its installer, it's still the same

Comment: It is hard to justify the cause with this minimal info. Try to reinstall sdk, check if that file exist, repair vs installation, check any error in the project itself etc.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Oh, how didn't I come up with that! But every time it happens (not only on my PC, and not only to VS2019), and I do a reinstallation, the issue remains a mystery, and I would like to know what caused this. Thanks anyway!